# PHP video chat third party application

Tags: php, video-streaming, video-processing, video-conferencing

I am building a PHP app, which needs to do web conferencing call between my users. Can you please suggest a good third party tool/plugin/app which I can use, which has -

1. easy to plug in my app
2. provides api to fiddle around with it
3. (customization) good performance, as far as network data transfer is
           concerned
4. reliable

I know this is not a correct forum for this, but any help is greatly appreciated.

PS - So far, I liked ooVoo developers work. I am finding a lot of apps already built on internet, but I want to know which one is the best (and free of course).

Comment: looking  for video-conferencing "tokbox "may be use full

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest WebRTC. There are many good tutorials available for integration also. Please have a look.

https://github.com/pusher/pusher-webrtc-chat-demo

https://github.com/ltribolet/webrtc-example

https://github.com/ltribolet/webrtc-example/blob/master/index.php

Also not forget to check [this site](http://www.webrtc.org/)